# Bootstrap Loading State not working in erb view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap "Loading" state (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) for a submit button in my rails application but it doesn't seem to work. My old code is:

```
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

and I replaced it with

```
 <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :id => "loading-example-btn", :data-loading-text => "Loading..." %>
```

like the example says.

However, now I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `loading' for #<#<Class:0x1c60494a>:0xb590dde>
```

which I'm assuming means that the "data-loading-text" part isn't working... does anyone know why that is or can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :id => "loading-example-btn", :data => { loading_text => "Loading..." } %>
```

or

```
<%= f.submit nil, class: "btn btn-primary",id: "loading-example-btn", data: { loading_text: "Loading..."}  %>
```

The last option works on FF 35.0